# GC generation after resurrection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Suppose an object has a `Finalize()` method.

When it is first created, a pointer in the finalization queue was added.

The object has no references .

When a garbage collection occurs, it moves the reference from the finalization queue to the f-reachable queue and a thread is started to run the `Finalize` method (sequentially after other objects' `Finalize` methods).

So the object now (after resurrection) has only one root  which is the pointer from the f-reachable queue.

At this point, does/did the object get promoted to the next generation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can just try.  Run this code in the Release build without a debugger attached:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var obj = new Foo();
        // There are 3 generations, could have used GC.MaxGeneration
        for (int ix = 0; ix < 3; ++ix) {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Foo {
    int attempt = 0;
    ~Foo() {
        // Don't try to do this over and over again, rough at program exit
        if (attempt++ < 3) {
            GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
            Console.WriteLine(GC.GetGeneration(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   2

So it stays in the generation it got moved to by the collection, moving to the next one on each collection until it hits the last one.  Which makes sense in general.

Comment: p.s. why without a debugger attached ( just curious)

Comment: So the debugger doesn't cause the jitter to extend the life-time of the *obj* variable to the end of the method.  Which would prevent GC.Collect from collecting *obj*.

Comment: This is above my level. I would be helped by some comments in the code, why you count attempts and why you loop three times etc.

Comment: @JohanLarsson 3 times is for showing the progress at the generation chain. it could be also 3+ .... regarding the attempt is because : if he wouldn't count the attempts - it will be live forever. cause he always re-register the finalizer .

Comment: There are 3 GC generations.  The "attempts" variable is there to prevent the finalizer thread from going bonkers trying to finalize the object at program exit and not succeeding.  Just try it and see what happens when you remove it, that's why I posted this code.  It's fun to watch it trying.  You now also see the 2 second timeout applied at program exit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the answer is yes, this will happen. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx says:

> ... Two GCs are required to reclaim memory used by objects that require finalization. In reality, more than two collections may be necessary since the objects *could get promoted to an older generation*.